# Forest: Terminal nodes associated with multiple branches

Tags: forest

I would like to draw family tree diagrams like the following, where the terminal nodes are associated with multiple branches.

[image]

My current workaround is to carve up the phrase I want to use at the terminal nodes, associate a branch with each section of the phrase, then manually adjust the x values (see MWE). This is complicated and ugly.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  where n children=0{tier=1}{}
  [Language family, for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north, l=20mm}
    [(Ma, before drawing tree={x+=6.1em}]
    [ny, before drawing tree={x+=4.8em}]
    [su, before drawing tree={x+=3.9em}]
    [bg, before drawing tree={x+=2.6em}]
    [ro, before drawing tree={x+=1.3em}]
    [ups)]
    [Subgroup X]
    [Subgroup Y]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Is there is simple and elegant way to get what I’m looking for? Using `roof` is not an option, because the point of the diagram is to emphasise the number of branches.

Comment: Is it an option to use tikz instead? Might be easier if this is not something you are about to do many times as `forest` is not supposed to have multiple lines from the same parent to the same child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `forest` environment seem like it is not meant to have multiple lines between the same parent and child, I believe that in this case, `tikz` is a better way of doing it.

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (language family) at (0,0) {Language family};
        \node (subgroup x) [below right=15mm and -15mm of language family] {Subgroup X};
        \node (subgroup y) [right=5mm of subgroup x] {Subgroup Y};
        \node (many subgroups) [left=5mm of subgroup x] {(Many subgroups)};

    \draw (language family.south)
        edge (subgroup y)
        edge (subgroup x)
        edge ([xshift=-12mm]many subgroups.north)
        edge ([xshift=-7.2mm]many subgroups.north)
        edge ([xshift=-2.4mm]many subgroups.north)
        edge ([xshift=2.4mm]many subgroups.north)
        edge ([xshift=7.2mm]many subgroups.north)
        edge ([xshift=12mm]many subgroups.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```